# PHP error cannot post in react using create-react-app

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

I am making a react login form. the problem is that if I use POST the php document gives an error "Cannot POST /action.php" and if I use GET it gives the same form again and submitting don't work.
My js code("App.js") ```

```
import "./App.css";

function Inp(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <label for={props.name}>{props.prompt}:&nbsp;</label>
      <br></br>
      <input
        name={props.name}
        type={props.type}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
}
function Form() {
  return (
    <form action="action/action.php" method="POST">
      <Inp
        prompt="Your email"
        placeholder="Email"
        type="email"
        name="Email"
      ></Inp>
      <Inp
        prompt="Your password"
        placeholder="Pass"
        type="password"
        name="Pass"
      ></Inp>
      <input type="submit"></input>
    </form>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Form></Form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
My php code-
```

```
You are successfully logined as <?php echo $_POST["Email"];?>
```

Comment: Are you certain you have the correct path to `action.php`?

Comment: Yes the path is correct